# Laravel copy row from one datatable to another

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to copy a row from a datatable A to a datatable B with Laravel.

I try with :

```
$coeff_insert = DB::insert('INSERT INTO '.$copro_id.'.coeff_etages SELECT * FROM aurora.coeff_etages WHERE id = '.$coeff_max.';');
```

`$copro_id` is my datatable A name that is dynamic.

`aurora.coeff_etages` is my datatable B that's always call like this.

But it doesn't work. No error message but nothing happen.

Someone can help me ?

Thank for your help.

Comment: try turning errors on, check you log files

Comment: DB::table('you missing the table name')->insert(), you may run a raw sql or change you sql to array()

Comment: I tred $coeff_insert = DB::table('coeff_etages')->insert('SELECT * FROM aurora.coeff_etages WHERE id = '.$coeff_max.';'); but I have an error about a Integrity constraint violation.

Comment: because you are insert('a query STRING'), read https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#inserts , may be save the query to a variable first then pass to the DB::table(...